# Is Asynchronous function useful in case of buffer pool destroyed?

Tags: apache-flink

I am doing a project in apache flink where I need to call multiple APIs so as to achieve my goal. The result of each API is required for the next API to work. Also as I am doing it on a KeyedStream, the same flow will be applicable to multiple data at once.

Below dig. can explain the scenario

```
                   /------API1---API2----
   KeyedStream ----|------API1---API2----
                   \------API1---API2----
```

As I am doing all this, I am getting an exception saying "Buffer pool destroyed" after the job runs for sometime. Is it something related to API call, do I need to make use of Asynchronous function?? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a few things that are typically needed to help answer questions about Flink...

1. What version are you running?
2. How are you running it (from IDE, YARN cluster, stand-alone, etc)?
3. What's the **complete** stack trace for the exception?
4. (often) Can you share your code?

But at a high level, the "buffer pool destroyed" message you mentioned is not the root cause of failover, it's just a byproduct of Flink trying to kill off the workflow after an error has happened. So you need to dig deeper in the logs (typically Task Manager logs are where you'd look first).